# when was the terminology of "general" vs "special" linear group first used?

Tags: reference-request, math-history

This is a reference request. I would like to understand the first use of the phrase "special linear group" to denote $SL_n$. In particular, I would like to understand whether it predates the current definition of a vector space.

Comment: Maybe the History of Science and Math site would be a better place for this question. https://hsm.stackexchange.com/